# Output true/false if value includes a keyword from another table

Tags: postgresql

I want to output a column which indicates if the value in `offers.heading` includes a keyword from  `keyword.keyword`.

Table offers

```
| heading  |
| -------- |
| first one should be true 
| second one should be false
```

Table keyword

```
| keyword |
| --------|
| first   |
| true    |
```

Result:

```
| heading                     | keyword         |
| --------                    | --------------  |
| first one should be true    | true            |
| second one should be false  | false           |
```

The best I could come up with is using join, this however outputs multiple matches and not in true/false format

```
SELECT
    offers.heading,
    match.keyword
FROM offers
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT keyword
    FROM keyword
) AS match(keyword) ON offers.heading LIKE '%' || match.keyword || '%'


| heading                     | keyword         |
| --------                    | --------------  |
| first one should be true    | true            |
| first one should be true    | first           |
| second one should be false  | null            |
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can try to use `EXISTS` in `SELECT` instead of `JOIN` because that might match more than one row by `first one should be true`

```
SELECT
    o.heading,
    EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM keyword k WHERE o.heading LIKE '%' || k.keyword || '%')
FROM offers o
```

if you want to get `True` or `False` string value we can use `CASE WHEN` expression.

```
SELECT
    o.heading,
    (CASE WHEN EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM keyword k WHERE o.heading LIKE '%' || k.keyword || '%') THEN 'True' ELSE 'False' END) keyword
FROM offers o
```

[sqlfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=8860e511ab9e956dc4ac3b5f1bfd2ee5)

Answer (score 0):

It is easier to join using `~` which is a regex like.
We can use an assertion `keyword is not null` which returns `t`rue or `f`alse. `Distinct` avoids having more than one row per heading.

> ```
> create table headings (heading varchar(285)); 
> insert into headings values('first one should be true'),('second one should be false'),('third one no match');
> create table keywords(keyword varchar(10));
> insert into keywords values('first'),('true');
> select
> ```

> ```
> create table headings (heading varchar(285)); 
> insert into headings values('first one should be true'),('second one should be false'),('third one no match');
> create table keywords(keyword varchar(10));
> insert into keywords values('first'),('true');
> ```

> ```
> select distinct
>   heading,
>   keyword is not null  keyword
> from headings
> left join keywords
> on heading ~ keyword
> ;
> ```
>
> ```
> heading                    | keyword
> :------------------------- | :------
> first one should be true   | t      
> second one should be false | f      
> third one no match         | f
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=113d12deed4d5cef43dc34f7654089a2)*

Comment: The CASE expression can be simplified to `keyword is not null`

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name thank you - answer modified (simplified)